# How to auto show unarchived files in Finder?

Tags: archive

Currently [Archive Utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_Utility) is configured to unzip all archives opened by me in their directory.

While this is good it is not enough for me, I want it to show me the result in Finder.

How can I obtain this behavior, is there a hidden switch?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Archive Utility.app, I recommend [The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html). It'll show the extracted files  in Finder. (I'm not sure if it's default behavior but you can change the setting in preferences.)

Comment: +1 I would prefer to stay with the default one if possible but if I get no answer for it in few days I will accept your answers. Thanks!